# Load a text file and remove duplicates and count logins

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, arraylist, hashmap

I am getting stuck in getting this java assignment started. Any help would be appreciated. I have two text files:

1) User log (2MB)

```
UserID  Activity        TimeStamp
asdf    login       1279246015000
asdf    login       1280264668000
aaa     login       1280265253000
aaa     purchase    1279121883000
abc     login   1279122061000
```

2) UserProfile

```
UserID     Website
asdf       aaa.com
aaa        abc.com
abc        aaa.com
```

I need to output the following information:

```
Number of logins     Total users aaa.com    abc.com
1                    xxx                    xxx
2
3
4
etc...
```

The expected output is this: "Number of logins" are the count of logins performed in the log file, grouped by activity. So the first row should display the total number of users that have logged in only once from the aaa.com website, abc.com website etc. broken out by website.  The second row indicates the total number of users from aaa.com, abc.com etc... that have logged in two times; and so forth.

The userlog and userprofile text files need to be deduplicated.

Comment: THe expected output shown is not clear. Can you explain what is the expected output from the two files

Comment: the expected output is the following:
"Number of logins" are the count of logins performed in the log file group by activity. So the first row should display the total number of users that have login only once from the aaa.com website, abc.com website etc....

The second rows should indicate the total number of users from aaa.com, abc.com etc... that have login two times etc...

Comment: Have we tried using a ``Set``? Should "remove" the duplicates as you wish, meaning we have to provide the correct ``compare`` method to the Set.

Comment: Sublimotion - I copied info from your comment into question.  You should edit question rather than scattering bits of info in comments.  You need to say if purchases and logins have separate tables or lines in table or whatever

Answer (score 0):

For a 2Mb log file a simple program that read the file, and count elements would run in few seconds (may be less).

---

Use should use Maps (java dictionary) :

- a Map for UserProfiles : key = user id, value = site
- a Map to count
  logins by sites, the key of this Map is the site, value = count.

Each time you read a line of log, you get the site of the user id from the userprofiles map and youd increments the count of logins by sites for this site in the countLogins map.